# Getting issue on exporting credit memo for selected one from admin grid

Tags: magento

I am getting issue on exporting the selected credit memo grid. It is only occurring with the credit memo. Other export is working fine with shipment, invoice, and order.

I am also attaching the error screenshot.
[credit memo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZYu3.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have an SQL query error while exporting the Credit memo data, it happens whenever you something deleted a record in your database.

Can you please elaborate on more steps:

-Did you delete some orders associated with the credit memo?
-Did you delete some invoices of any order?

Please check and confirm also check the record with entity_id = 1052 in your database table. Run the below query:

```
Select * from sales_creditmemo_grid where entity_id = 1052
Select * from sales_creditmemo_grid where entity_id = 1179
Select * from sales_creditmemo where entity_id = 1179
Select * from sales_creditmemo where entity_id = 1052
```

Comment: On checking the system.log file found the error which states this:

[2022-09-19 05:26:13] main.ERROR: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'entity_id' in where clause is ambiguous, query was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `sales_creditmemo_grid` AS `main_table`
 LEFT JOIN `sales_creditmemo` AS `creditmemos` ON main_table.entity_id = creditmemos.entity_id WHERE  (((`entity_id` IN('1', '2')))) [] []

Comment: on checking this query on the DB the query should be like this:

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `sales_creditmemo_grid` AS `main_table`
 LEFT JOIN `sales_creditmemo` AS `creditmemos` ON main_table.entity_id = creditmemos.entity_id WHERE  main_table.entity_id IN('1', '2') 

What can the issue by which the where clause is not adding the main table?

Comment: The issue is Where clause entry couldn't find the record with entity_id 1 or 2. Did you try to execute the query? There is a database table entry issue with that main table entity_id.

Comment: Yes, I have tried the SQL command to DB It is executed. How can I add the main table name in the where clause? As for other export, it is working fine [ order, invoice etc ]

Comment: It would be this: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sales_creditmemo_grid AS main_table LEFT JOIN sales_creditmemo AS creditmemos ON main_table.entity_id = creditmemos.entity_id WHERE main_table.entity_id IN('1179') OR SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sales_creditmemo_grid AS main_table LEFT JOIN sales_creditmemo AS creditmemos ON main_table.entity_id = creditmemos.entity_id WHERE creditmemos .entity_id IN('1179')

Answer (score 0):

Maybe another way to fix this is if you have added a third-party module that has its own Credit memo Grid within the module to show placed credit memo of each order. This is also conflicting because it is using entity_id from sales_creditmemo_grid as well.

Error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'entity_id' in where clause is ambiguous.

So, you can try in your credit memo collection file and change the method like:

Replaced this:

```
->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', ['in', $creditmemoIds]);
```

With this:

```
->addFieldToFilter('main_table.entity_id', ['in' => $creditmemoIds]);
```

Now all is well! No conflicts!